# Скрыть Menu в Fragment android java

Tags: java, android

Задача : в определенном `Fragment`  показывать меню (добавить кнопку в `ActionBar`), в остальных скрывать.

Попытка реализации :

В главном активити:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.clisents_request_item, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.request:
            return false;

    }
    return (super.onOptionsItemSelected(item));
}
```

В `Fragment`, где нужно показать :

```
   @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        // Do something that differs the Activity's menu here
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
       
        final MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.request);
        //to-do
    }
```

В `Fragment`, где нужно скрыть:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(false);
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    menu.clear();
}
```

но `Menu` все равно отображается во всех `Fragment`, как скрыть `Menu` в определенных `Fragments` ?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно убирать меню из родительской активности при переходе на определенный фрагмент. В месте где происходит выбор (при нажатии на кнопку, выбор пункта BottomNavigationView) скрываете тулбар:

```
getSupportActionBar().hide();(kotlin - supportActionBar!!.hide())
```

или показываете там где вам нужно:

```
getSupportActionBar().show();(kotlin - supportActionBar!!.show())
```

вызов приведенных функций нужно делать из активности. Дальше в фрагменте где у вас показан тулбар вы добавляете меню способом который указан в вашем вопросе. Но так же я бы советовал добавить проверку наличия тулбара, чтобы не засетить меню на пустое место.